# Kafka - Different KafkaProducers in same transaction

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, avro

For migration purpose, we need to produce records using two different serialisers, and thus two different KafkaProducers ( one String and one Avro) in the same transaction.
But all the  transaction stuff is done through one KafkaProducer instance as follows :

```
kafkaProducer.beginTransaction();
...
kafkaProducer.send(record);
...
kafkaProducer.commitTransaction();
```

Can I use a second kafkaProducer (with the second serializer) and use the same transactionnal.id and do like this :

```
kafkaProducer.beginTransaction();
...
kafkaProducer.send(record);
kafkaProducer2.send(record);
...
kafkaProducer.commitTransaction();
```

All will be part of the same transaction , all consistent ?

EDIT 1 :

According to what I saw in the java implementation, there is some mechanism when calling commitTransaction() like calling flush() on the producer itself.. so I think the model above won't work..
Any chance of achieving this without instantiating a full new instance of everything in parallel ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single producer active in a transaction at a time.

If you start 2 producers with the same `transactional.id`, one of them will be fenced and won't be able to commit its records and all ecords won't be part of the same transaction.

You need to use a single producer and one possible workaround is to configure it to use the `BytesSerializer` and handle the convertion of your `Objects` to bytes in your logic explicitely.

Comment: I thought it would be fenced if I call the initTransaction() of the second producer, but in my example I don't. And using BytesSerializer is too complex if I want to benefits from AvroSerDes I think..